# Why is my scaffolding-generated code not passing the scaffolding-generated Rspec tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

here's the rspec tests:

```
describe "POST create" do
  describe "with valid params" do
    it "creates a new User" do
      expect {
        post :create, {:user => valid_attributes}, valid_session
      }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
    end

    it "assigns a newly created user as @user" do
      post :create, {:user => valid_attributes}, valid_session
      assigns(:user).should be_a(User)
      assigns(:user).should be_persisted
    end

    it "redirects to the created user" do
      post :create, {:user => valid_attributes}, valid_session
      response.should redirect_to(User.last)
    end
  end
end
```

And here's the controller code:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

and here are my failures:

```
  1) UsersController POST create with valid params creates a new User
 Failure/Error: expect {
   count should have been changed by 1, but was changed by 0
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:68:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) UsersController POST create with valid params assigns a newly created user as @user
 Failure/Error: assigns(:user).should be_persisted
   expected persisted? to return true, got false
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:77:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) UsersController POST create with valid params redirects to the created user
 Failure/Error: response.should redirect_to(User.last)
   Expected response to be a <redirect>, but was <200>
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:82:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) UsersController PUT update with valid params redirects to the user
 Failure/Error: response.should redirect_to(user)
   Expected response to be a <redirect>, but was <200>
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:124:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

This feels like a configuration problem since everything looks right to me. But I could be wrong.

UPDATE:
from the users_controller.rb

```
    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:title, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password_digest, :admin)
    end
```

and from the spec:

```
let(:valid_attributes) { { title: "MyString", first_name: "Example", last_name: "User", email: "my@address.com", password: "password", password_confirmation: "password" } }

let(:valid_session) { {} }
```

and my users.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  validates :first_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :last_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence:   true,
                format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }

  has_many :users_to_groups, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :groups, :through => :users_to_groups
end
```

Comment: `rake db:test:prepare`?, any database_cleaner options?

Comment: i've run `rake db:test:prepare` before every run of tests. what is `database_cleaner`? my test database appears to remain empty.

Comment: Is there anything in User class?  Validations, etc?  What's the definition for user_params in UsersController?

Comment: what is assigned to valid_attributes and valid_session?

Comment: check **log/test.log**

Comment: see my update. checking log/test.log now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with my user_params. It should be `:password` and `:password_confirmation` (not `:password_digest`)

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:title, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :admin)
end
```